# Why is $\zeta'/\zeta(s) = -\sum_p \log p/(p^{s}-1)$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm going through the prime number theorem and there's a lemma which uses the fact that $\frac{\zeta'}{\zeta}(s) = -\sum_p \frac{\log p}{p^{s}-1}$.

Can somebody explain this? Am I missing something obvious?

Here's my work, $\log \zeta (s) = -\sum_p \log(1 - p^{-s})$, so $\frac{\zeta'}{\zeta}(s) = -\sum_p \frac{sp^{-s-1}}{p^{-s}-1}$. How did the logarithm on the top come in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logarithm in the numerator comes from the chain rule when differentiating with respect to $s$. You get $1-p^{-s}$ in the denominator from the derivate of the logarithm, and then you have to multiply by the derivative of the argument of the logarithm, i.e. the derivative of $1-p^{-s}$ with respect to $s$. Writing this as $1-e^{-s (\log p)}$ and using the chain rule once again gives the $\log p$ you mention.

Comment: @muffle Can you explain your work more? It looks like you might be trying to combine sums and logs in ways that they can't, as well as maybe differentiating with respect to $p$ rather than $s$. Take a look here: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Logarithmic_Derivative_of_Riemann_Zeta_Function

Comment: Thanks! For some reason, I differentiated $p$ instead of $s$. After four years of university too! So embarrassing...